# nginx configuration: referencing files in different docker container

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm in the process of dockerizing a web app.

I have a webpack script running in a container that generates a set of static files in a `/dist` subfolder - HTML, JS, CSS and images. There is NO web server involved at this point, just a watcher command that does all this (`npm run start`). I'm relying on bind mounting so that changes made locally get copied to the container where the watcher runs, regenerating the static files.

This is working well but I'm stumped on the next step: getting nginx - running in a different container - to be able to load those static assets from the other container.

It's my understanding that I can't use nginx `upstream` here because there's no server to point to (just a folder). I also can't combine my nginx config into the same docker container containing my webapp generation as a multi stage build because both require watchers, and I gather it's bad practice with docker to have multiple processes running like that.

Any suggestions on the relevant nginx config to allow this?

Comment: Do you need nginx running in a separate container in dev or just prod? If you can avoid a separate nginx container in dev that would be convenient. You could always do your build process with `npm` for prod and just package the generated files into a `nginx` docker image.

Comment: Thanks, good points. I was trying to keep dev + prod as close as possible, but referencing an npm package for prod like you suggest is super clean. I really just needed the separate containers for dev. But now I'm wondering if I shouldn't abandon this approach and just hook up a basic express server for local dev to serve up static assets + use nginx for prod only.

Comment: Yeah I'd keep nginx out of local dev and maybe if anything, Dockerize the npm app for local dev. You could have your Dockerfile for that have a default command of `npm run start` and then when you use it the same image for your build, you can just run a different command to build.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. You've been a big help!